# login website like(FB, TWITTER ) and crawl data with c#?

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs, web-crawler

I am creating a console application in c#(visual studio).
but i don't know where to start.
1st i want to login(phantomjs or selenium)>>then go to a (specified)website URL and extract html?
i want to know how to save login information in my web request.
thank you.

Comment: login information is in form of cookies and when you login is saved as cookies in browser, so you do not need to have concern about it.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail with the help of suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, it's not easy to do that just with web request because each site has its own way of managing cookies and security.

It's easier if you use a web browser control to login first. From there, the browser can obtain a valid cookie and you can start crawl data from there.

I've done a similar thing with Chegg website. For details, you can check out my repository https://github.com/hungqcao/chegg-solutions-saver

In your case, it can get a little complicated since FB, Twitter may have 2-factor authentication or something similar to that but the idea stays the same.

Let me know if you need help.